# Get count of active AJAX requests with Selenium

Tags: php, selenium, yii

I test my Yii-app on Selenium. For waiting execution AJAX request I use:

```
$this->waitForCondition('selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().jQuery.active == 0');
```

It`s works. How I can get count of active AJAX requests? This code:

```
$count = '+';
$this->storeEval('selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().jQuery.active;', $count);
echo $count;
```

display `+`

To check the active requests I tryed used:

```
if ($this->verifyEval('selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().jQuery.active', 0)) echo 'active requests more than 0';
```

but it`s returned errors:

```
Failed command: verifyEval('selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().jQuery.active', '0')
Failed asserting that '1' matches PCRE pattern "/^0$/".
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself

`$this->getEval('selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().jQuery.active')`